# Reloading the tableview inside a ViewController getting me ' Fatal error: index out of range' , in cellforRow at index path

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

When I open the view it opens up quickly and doesn't show any errors but when I reopen it, it gives me 'fatal error'. This is a tableview inside the ViewController which is getting me the data but when I reopen the view it gives error.

The tableview is embedded inside the view controller when I call the tableview again it gives fatal error index out of range inside the ViewController. This needs to be solved I think issue is in my number of rows in section returning the array.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Foundation

protocol Quantitypass {
    func qtypass(qty: String, product_id: String)
}

public struct QtyCart {
    var qty : String!

    public init(qty: String) {
        self.qty = qty
    }
}

public struct FavouriteCart {
    var p_name : String!
    var p_price : String!
    var p_id : String!
    var qty: String!

    public init(p_name: String ,  p_price: String , p_id : String, qty: String) {
        self.p_name = p_name
        self.p_price = p_price
        self.p_id = p_id
        self.qty = qty
    }
}

public struct favSection {
    var favitems: [FavouriteCart]

    public init(favitems: [FavouriteCart]  ) {
        self.favitems = favitems
    }
}

public struct MyVariables {
    static var product2 = "p_id"
}

public var cartData: [favSection] = []

class newCartViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnSubmit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.loadnextVC()
    }

    func loadnextVC() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "finalVC")
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lblPreorder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOrdermethod: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTotalAmount: UILabel!

    // public var itemsData: [Item] = []
    var lblOrder = String()
    // let productPrice = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "p_price")
    let cartid = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "deviceUUID") as? String
    let getApi = RestaurantAPI.self

    var qtyData: [QtyCart] = []
    //    var currentSection = 0
    //    var currentRow = 1
    // var calculation1 = cartTableViewCell()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.lblTotalAmount.text = ""
    }

    //public var cartData: [FavouriteCart] = []
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var buttonClicked = statusViewController.self
    var btn2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"button1") as? Bool
    var btn3: Bool =  true
    weak var delegate: DetailsDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getTotal1()
        print("@------/\(cartData.count)")

        //self.updateLabel(withString: lblTotalAmount.text)
        if btn2 != btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = true
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = false
            print("BUTTONCLICKED")
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        } else if btn2 == btn3 {
            lblPreorder.isHidden = false
            lblOrdermethod.isHidden = true
            print("BUTTON-NOT-CLICKED")
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "button1")
        }

        //        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        //        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        //        } else {
        //        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        //
        //        }
        //        self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
        //        self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newCartViewController.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        //
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        self.getTotal1()
        self.getFav()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        // self.updateTableview()
        // self.getTotal1()
    }

    func getFav() {
        getFav(completionHandler: { success in
            if success {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    //TOTAL API CALL:
    func getTotal1() {
        if cartid != nil {
            let request = getApi.getamountcartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId: cartid!)
            Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print("123321#######/\(response)")
                    let res = response
                    print("101res/\(res)")

                    if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
                            if success == false {
                                // var  grandtotal: Any?  = value["total"]
                                if let grandtotal = value["total"] as? Double {
                                    self.lblTotalAmount.text = String(grandtotal)
                                    print("!@/\(String(grandtotal))")
                                    var g = String(grandtotal)
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(g, forKey: "g")
                                }
                                // self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    //
    // Mark: getting all cart items:-->
    func getFav(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        if cartid != nil {
            let request = getApi.displaycartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId:cartid!)
            Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .get , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print("123321/\(response)")
                    let res = response
                    print("101res/\(res)")

                    //                let total =  cartData
                    //                print("cartd1/\(total)")

                    if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
                            if success == false {
                                print("2222/\(response)")
                                if let response = value["cartdata"]  as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                    let cart = response["simple"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                                    //                let total = value["total"] as! [String: Any]
                                    //                print("1231231231234/\(total)")
                                    //let userdata: [Favourites] = []
                                    //
                                    var cartitems: [FavouriteCart] = []
                                    for (_ , value) in cart.enumerated() {

                                        let obj = value
                                        let p_name = obj["p_name"] as! String
                                        let p_price = obj["p_price"] as! String
                                        let p_id = obj["p_id"] as! String
                                        let qty = obj["qty"] as! String

                                        //  UserDefaults.standard.set(qty, forKey: "qty")

                                        let item = FavouriteCart(p_name: p_name, p_price: p_price, p_id: p_id, qty: qty)

                                        cartitems.append(item)

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                            print("RELOADED-----ON-----API")
                                            cartData.append(favSection(favitems: cartitems))
                                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                print("COMPLETION-------------HANDLER")
                                completionHandler(true)
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert",message:value["error_msg"] as? String,preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default , handler: nil)
                            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    // Mark:--> Delete items from cart.
    // func delFav(p_id: String ,completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    func delFav(p_id: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        //var product1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "p_id")
        //print("this is my \(product1)")
        let request = getApi.deleteproductcartGetWithRequestBuilder(restId: "17", cartId: cartid!, productId: p_id , freeDish: "none", type: "simple")
        Alamofire.request(request.URLString, method: .delete , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("del favvvvvvvvv\(response)")
                print("<<DELETED ------------ ITEM>>")
                //print(response)
                if let value = response.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let success = value["error"] as? Bool {
                        if success == false {
                            let response = value["cartdata"] as? [String]
                            print("10001 - > /\(response)")

                            //self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } else
                        {
                            print("error message")
                        }
                    }
                }
                // completionHandler(true)
        }
    }


    func delterow(p_id: String) {
        self.delFav(p_id: p_id, completionHandler: {sucess in
            if sucess {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("DELETED_ITEM")
            }
        })
    }

    func updateTotal(withString string: String?) {
        lblTotalAmount.text = string
    }

}

extension newCartViewController: UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource  {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90;
    }

    //     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //        return cartData.count
    //    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return sectionsData[section].items.count
        // return cartData[section].favitems.count
        //  return cartData[section]..count
        return cartData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartTablecell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
        let item: FavouriteCart = cartData[indexPath.section].favitems[indexPath.row]

        cell.btnsub1.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnadd1.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.lblItemName.text = item.p_name
        cell.productPrice.text = item.p_price
        cell.lblprice.text = item.p_price
        cell.lblQuantity.text = item.qty

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool{
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle ==  .delete) {
            if cartData.isEmpty{
                print("EmptyCart")
            }else {
                print("0-0/\(cartData.count)")
                // let item: Item = sectionsData[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
                let item: FavouriteCart = cartData[indexPath.section].favitems[indexPath.row]

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                cartData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                self.delterow(p_id: item.p_id)
                self.getTotal1()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was giving the error because the rows were saved at local but I was calling the data again changes are :

have to delete the whole cart when close the view

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      self.lblTotalAmount.text = ""
      cartData.removeAll()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **self.tableView.dataSource = self & self.tableView.delegate = self** should be in viewDidLoad method. Adding it to viewDidLoad might work.